# How to coerce an `integer` to a `data.frame`?

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, rhandsontable

I want a column of one table to be a sumproduct of two columns of another table as given in the following script. When I run the code in RStudio, the following error message is popping up: "Error in as: no method or default for coercing 'integer' to 'data.frame' ".

Can someone explain and amend, what is wrong in the script?

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(rhandsontable)
    library(data.table)
    library(dplyr)

    DF1 = data.table(
        "Batch"= as.character(),
        "Amount of goods"= as.numeric(0),
        "Unit cost of goods"= as.numeric(0),
        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

    DF2= data.table(
        "Cost of goods available for sale" = as.numeric(0),
        "Cost of goods sold" = as.numeric(0),
        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "Accounting"),
      dashboardSidebar(
        menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
        menuItem("Measurement", tabName = "measurement", 
              menuSubItem("Inventory", tabName = "table1")
        )
      ),
      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
          tabItem(
            tabName = "table1",
            column(
              "DF1",
          width = 12,
              rHandsontableOutput("Table1")
            ),
            column(
              "DF2",
          width = 12,
              rHandsontableOutput("Table2")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

      data <- reactiveValues()

      observe({
        input$recalc
        data$df1<- as.data.frame(DF1)
        data$df2 <- as.data.frame(DF2)
      })

      observe({
        if(!is.null(input$Table1))
          data$df1<- hot_to_r(input$Table1)
      })

      observe({
        if(!is.null(input$Table2))
          data$df2 <- hot_to_r(input$Table2)
      })

    sumProduct1<-reactive({data$df1%>%
               summarize(sum(`Amount of goods` * `Unit cost of goods`))}) 

    observe({data$df2$`Cost of goods available for sale` <- sumProduct1()})

    output$Table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(data$df1, stretchH = "all") |> 
          hot_cols(colWidths = c(300, 150, 150))
    })

    output$Table2 <- renderRHandsontable({
       rhandsontable(data$df2, stretchH = "all") |> 
          hot_cols(colWidths = c(150, 150))
    })
   }
   
   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Since your `data$df1 %>% summarize(sum(..))` returns a single column (unless `df` is grouped), then that is all there is to return. Might I suggest instead using `sumProduct1 <- reactive({ with(data$df1, sum(\`Amount of goods\` * \`Unit cost of goods\`)) })`? That is a vector (not a frame), which should work in your existing `observe({ data$df2$... <- ... })` assignment without need for further changes.

Comment: When you have errors in shiny apps, I urge you to do two things: (1) Attempt your code _outside of shiny_. Developing something for the first time in shiny can easily over-complicate things, masking your ability to "look at" objects easily. (2) Learn debugging in R. This includes the `browser()` and `debug(..)` functions (read about both), and stepping through code exactly when and where problems occur. This takes practice but will help immensely. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html is a good reference as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sumProduct1()` reactive expression returns a summarized data frame with one column containing the sumproduct. In your observe function, you're trying to assign this data frame directly to a single column of data$df2:

Change:

```
 observe({data$df2$`Cost of goods available for sale` <- sumProduct1()})
```

with:

```
  observe({
    if(!is.null(sumProduct1())){
      data$df2$`Cost of goods available for sale` <- sumProduct1()[[1]]
    }
  })
```

Comment: TarJae, your solution worked well. Can you also explain the role of `[[1]] in the snippet you suggested? In order to figure out I tried to change [[1]] to other numeric, e.g. to [[2]], but the script did not work at all.

Comment: `[[1]]` is simple R indexing, returning the first element from `list`-like object (which includes `data.frame`, for which it will always return the first column). If you use `[[2]]` on an object that does not have 2 or more (columns), you will get something like `Error: subscript out of bounds`.

Comment: @r2evans thanky you for doing the job!